# Inserting calculated values during a for each loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this.

```
                    Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 500
                                [2] => 800
                            )

                         [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 100
                                [2] => 200
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 300
                                [2] => 400
                            )
                    )
```

I want to use a foreach loop (not a function) to do several things. First I just want to subtract subelement [1] from subelement [2] to generate sub element [3] and then insert subelement3 back into the output array. See below:

```
 $output=
                    Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 500
                                [2] => 800
                                [3] => 300
                            )

                         [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 100
                                [2] => 200
                                [3] => 100
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 400
                                [2] => 250
                                [3] => 150
                            )
                    )
```

To do the above I am using the for each loop below to generate the values of subelement 3 and it works ok. My problem is inserting the values back into the output array in the right place. I have commented out my last attempt which failed. Sorry if I am missing the obvious here.

```
                foreach($result as $sub)
                {   
                    //get values
                    $sub[3]=$sub[1]-$sub[2];
                    echo "<difference>".$sub[3]."<br>";//works ok

                    //insert values back into array
                    //$result[$sub[0]][3] = $sub[3];
                }

                print "<pre>";
                print_r($result);
                print "</pre>"; 
                die();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem:**

```
$result[$sub[0]][3] = $sub[3]; //= $result[1][3] = $sub[3]
```

`$sub[0]` always return 1 (according to your input array) so it's not what you're looking for.

**The solution:**

Use the `$array as $key => $val` format in your `foreach` loop
and then access the sub array according to the relevant key.

```
        foreach($result as $key => $sub)
        {   
            //get values
            $result[$key][3]=$sub[1]-$sub[2];
```

Comment: I will accept your answer in a few minutes. There is a time limiter before you can accept! (You smashed that record)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) too, it's more elegant:

```
$output = aray_map( function ($item) {
    $item[] = $sub[2] - $sub[1];
    return $item;
}, $arr);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/915ad2a3e5806f4d2cf7c85aea8fc4f86996719c)

Comment: another excellent answer. Thank you. I suspect Ofir was responding to the fact Ia asked for a for each solution